# Cpp GUI Tutorial

Tags: ros, tutorial, rqt

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

is there any tutorial, how to create a GUI, where I can publish messages on a certain topic for C++? Or can anyone provide a minimal Example, how to read and publish a integer?

Thanks

EDIT:
I tried to follow the tutorial : http : // ros.org/wiki/rqt/Tutorials/Writing%20a%20C%2B%2B%20Plugin

But somehow, when I try to load Cmakelists in QT Creator, I get following error:

> CMake Error at
> /opt/ros/groovy/share/catkin/cmake/safe_execute_process.cmake:11
> (message):
> execute_process(/usr/bin/python
> "/opt/ros/groovy/share/catkin/cmake/parse_package_xml.py"
> "/home/GUITest/rqt_mypkg/package.xml"
> "/home/GUITest/build/catkin_generated/package.cmake")
> returned error code 1 Call Stack (most
> recent call first):
> /opt/ros/groovy/share/catkin/cmake/catkin_package_xml.cmake:63
> (safe_execute_process)
> /opt/ros/groovy/share/catkin/cmake/catkin_package_xml.cmake:39
> (_catkin_package_xml)
> /opt/ros/groovy/share/catkin/cmake/catkin_package.cmake:95
> (catkin_package_xml)
> CMakeLists.txt:51 (catkin_package)
>
> ```
> return parse_package_string(f.read(),
> ```
>
> filename)   File
> "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/catkin_pkg/package.py",
> line 448, in parse_package_string
> raise InvalidPackage('Error(s) in %s:%s' % (filename, ''.join(['\n- %s'
> % e for e in errors])))
> catkin_pkg.package.InvalidPackage:
> Invalid package manifest
> "/home/GUITest/rqt_mypkg/package.xml":
> Error(s) in
> /home/GUITest/rqt_mypkg/package.xml:
>
> - The manifest must not contain the following tags: package Traceback
>   (most recent call last):   File
>   "/opt/ros/groovy/share/catkin/cmake/parse_package_xml.py",
>   line 98, in 
>   main()   File "/opt/ros/groovy/share/catkin/cmake/parse_package_xml.py",
>   line 90, in main
>   package = parse_package(args.package_xml)   File
>   "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/catkin_pkg/package.py",
>   line 315, in parse_package

Further, I don't get this from the tutorial:

**Basically the same step described in previous tutorial. Some unique cases:
Replace rqt_gui_py with rqt_gui_cpp
C++ binding specific note for xml attribute:
/library/class@name
The name of the plugin that is exported via the PLUGINLIB_DECLARE_CLASS macro**.

I just replaced rqt_gui_py with rqt_gui_cpp. But what is meant with C++ binding specific note for xml atribute? What should I do here exactly?

[EDIT] My plugin.xml looks like this:

```
<library path="src">
  <class name="MyPlugin" type="my_namespace::MyPlugin" base_class_type="rqt_gui_cpp::Plugin">
    <description>
      An example Python GUI plugin to create a great user interface.
    </description>
    <qtgui>
      <!-- optional grouping...
      <group>
        <label>Group</label>
      </group>
      <group>
        <label>Subgroup</label>
      </group>
      -->
      <label>My first CPP Plugin</label>
      <icon type="theme">system-help</icon>
      <statustip>Great user interface to provide real value.</statustip>
    </qtgui>
  </class>
</library>
```

I have following files:

- /home/GUITest/rqt_mypkg/package.xml
- /home/GUITest/rqt_mypkg/plugin.xml
- /home/GUITest/rqt_mypkg/CmakeLists.xml
- /home/GUITest/rqt_mypkg/my_namespace/my_plugin.h
- /home/GUITest/rqt_mypkg/my_namespace/my_plugin.cpp

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/69658/cpp-gui-tutorial/) by [invoices](https://answers.ros.org/users/5638/invoices/) on ROS Answers with karma: 21 on 2013-07-29

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [TommyP](https://answers.ros.org/users/1110/tommyp/) on 2013-07-30**:
Why are you using QT Creator? The tutorial does not mention this. Why not just try to follow the tutorial and take the example code and see if it compiles?

**Comment by [invoices](https://answers.ros.org/users/5638/invoices/) on 2013-07-30**:
If I try to call CMake in the console, I get the same error.

From this tutorial; http://ros.org/wiki/rqt/Tutorials/Create%20your%20new%20rqt%20plugin
I dont get the point 6 and below. I dont have a setup.py. Do I need it? Im not using python

**Comment by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) on 2013-07-30**:
@invoices I suppose that your original question is already answered. If so, you better open up a new question so that others can have a better view of what's your problem.

**Comment by [invoices](https://answers.ros.org/users/5638/invoices/) on 2013-07-31**:
Ok, I will create a new question as I still have not understood how to create my C++ RQT GUI

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I would put the ros::spin() in its own thread.

This is a good page:

http://www.ros.org/wiki/roscpp/Overview/Callbacks%20and%20Spinning

But what I would do for this problem is to write a rqt plugin in Python but you can also write it in C++:

http://ros.org/wiki/rqt/Tutorials

---

Originally posted by [TommyP](https://answers.ros.org/users/1110/tommyp/) with karma: 1339 on 2013-07-30

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1